# commands.Greedy in dpy does not raise error

Tags: discord, discord.py, nextcord

I have a kick command with commands.Greedy and I have proper error handler too but it never raise errors it even executes command when none of the argument provided

I want it to raise missing argument or invalid member provided errors

This is my code

```
 @commands.command(name='kick', help=".kick <user(s)> reason=None")

 @commands.is_owner()

 @commands.bot_has_guild_permissions(kick_members=True)

    async def _kick(self, ctx, members:commands.Greedy[discord.Member], *, reason=None):

        if len(members) > 10:

            return await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.colour.red(), description=f"{warn} | This command cannot accept more than 10 members."))
```

Comment: A greedy never returns an error, an "error" is just how the greedy decides to stop consuming arguments, so if the first argument is invalid it will just skip over it and go to the `reason` argument.